# Kafka cluster unavailable if a node in Zookeeper cluster dies

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am configuring a Kafka cluster of 3 brokers.
The cluster makes use of a Zookeeper cluster of 3 nodes.

Using Docker, this is how I started my 3 Zookeeper nodes:

```
docker run --net=my_network --name zoo1 -d -e ZOO_MY_ID=1 -e ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888" zookeeper

docker run --net=my_network --name zoo2 -d -e ZOO_MY_ID=2 -e ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888" zookeeper

docker run --net=my_network --name zoo3 -d -e ZOO_MY_ID=3 -e ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888" zookeeper
```

And this is how I started my 3 Kafka nodes:

```
docker run --net=my_network --name kafka1 -d -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181" wurstmeister/kafka

docker run --net=my_network --name kafka2 -d -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181" wurstmeister/kafka

docker run --net=my_network --name kafka3 -d -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3 -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT="zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181" wurstmeister/kafka
```

The Zookeeper and Kafka clusters behave well when tested independently.

I mean, I can connect to one of the Zookeeper nodes (say *zoo1*) and create a *znode*. I can stop the node afterwards (e.g., *docker stop zoo1*) and I can still query the *znode* from any other node in the Zookeeper cluster.

The Kafka cluster also behaves well. Assuming the 3 nodes in Zookeeper are up, I can create a topic, send a message, delete the broker leader, and verify that the message still can be consumed.

My problem is that the Kafka cluster stops working if one of the Zookeeper node dies.

For example, if I stop a zookeeper node (e.g., *docker stop zoo1*) and afterwards try to create a topic with this command:

```
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper "zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181" --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

I will receive an *UnknownHostException*:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:71)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1227)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:75)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:57)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:54)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: zoo3: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:69)
```

But I do need the Kafka cluster to be fully functional even if one of the machines hosting a Zookeeper node burns.
How I can reach that resilience?

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says, the host names may not be resolvable from where you are running create topic command. Try ping to zoo1, zoo2, zoo3 to check if they are resolving to correct IPs.

I don't think it is a Kafka problem. But Zookeeper host name resolution may not be happening correctly. I would suggest  first check if the Zookeeper ensemble works correctly when you shut down one of them by creating a new znode and reading a znode created before. Also, try passing Zookeeper IP addresses in the kafka-topics.sh commands in place of the host names.

When you restart the docker instance (say zoo1), it may start with a new IP. will zoo1 hostname be still resolvable from zoo2 and zoo3?

Comment: Hi. I know the exception points to one zookeeper host not being resolvable. Of course, I can ping to any of the zookeepers host while they are alive and I cannot ping them anymore if I explicitly kill them. Since I am precisely testing resilience, what I need is that the kafka cluster continues working even if one of the zookeeper nodes disappears from the network (so neither its hostname or its ip will be resolvable). I expect this to work as long as a quorum of Zookeeper nodes remain alive. The Zookeeper ensemble works correctly otherwise, I did the test of creating a znode as you suggested.

Comment: I think the Kafka cluster will work properly as long as Zookeeper quorum is available. Mostly there may be some problem with the kaka-topics.sh tool which internally invokes some Java classes only. We may manually check zookeeper znodes such as /brokers, /consumers, /controller etc. to check if the Kafka cluster is up and running fine.